# Creating shapefile and then edit it but get feature class does not participate in a network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, network-dataset

I want to mark the drainage but cannot do it as it gives an error saying:

> The create feature task could not be completed. The turn feature class
>   does not participate in a network dataset.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What were the precise steps that you performed when you saw this error starting with the steps you performed to create the shapefile, please?  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with these and any other details that will help make precisely what you have tried clearer.

Comment: The error message indicates a file geodatabase but you describe a shapefile data source. Are you using the wrong format?